# Linking SRT library in qmake project

Tags: windows, openssl, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I want to link SRT library into qmake project on my Windows machine.

I installed SRT v1.5.1 from https://github.com/Haivision/srt/releases/download/v1.5.1/libsrt-1.5.1-win-installer.zip.

In my .pri file, I have:

```
LIBS += "-LC:\Program Files (x86)\libsrt\lib\Debug-x64" -llibcrypto
LIBS += "-LC:\Program Files (x86)\libsrt\lib\Debug-x64" -lsrt
```

I'm getting following errors:

```
srt.lib(api.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol in6addr_any
srt.lib(channel.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __std_find_trivial_4 referenced in function "int const * __cdecl __std_find_trivial<int const ,int>(int const *,int const *,int)" (??$__std_find_trivial@$$CBHH@@YAPEBHPEBH0H@Z)
srt.lib(socketconfig.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_find_trivial_4
libcrypto.lib(libcrypto-lib-cryptlib.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetProcessWindowStation referenced in function OPENSSL_isservice
libcrypto.lib(libcrypto-lib-cryptlib.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetUserObjectInformationW referenced in function OPENSSL_isservice
libcrypto.lib(libcrypto-lib-cryptlib.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_MessageBoxW referenced in function OPENSSL_showfatal
```

I somewhat believe that I am missing DLLs since there are not any in C:\Program Files (x86)\libsrt\lib\Debug-x64 after libsrt-1.5.1-win-installer.zip installation, but I do not know where to get them when installer does not provide them (there are only libcrypto.lib, libssl.lib, and srt.lib in that directory). What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is a high probability that you are linking libraries that were built with a different platform toolset. For example, your solution is build in VS 2019 (toolset v142), but the 3rd party libstr is build with VS 2022 (toolset v143).